# What does 소취곡 mean?

Tags: translation

Challenging myself to translate a pretty big korean note and got stuck on this sentence '욕심이자 바람으로 팬들의 소취곡 퀸을 세상에 나오게 하고 싶어'.

Comment: Have you tried using google translate or any other online tool? Have you consulted a dictionary? What part are you having problem with?

Comment: I think it's clear what part the questioner has a problem with: I've never seen the word 소취곡 so I'm not sure what it means. Probably a typo or some kind of k-pop slang?

Comment: @user17915 I did look this up in naver dictionary and couldn't find it.

Comment: Then please post more context about the sentence like where is it from. What is the big note about, and a few sentences before and after this for context

Comment: Explicitly stated, 소취 is supposed to be short for 소원성취 (所願成就), so the problematic vocabulary is some kind of internet slang (소취곡; 所就曲).

Answer (score 2):

욕심이자 바람으로 => It is a desire or wish,

팬들의 소취곡 퀸을 => Queen or Queen's songs, which are fan's
favorite things,

세상에 나오게 => appear

하고 싶어 => I want

As a desire or wish, I want that Queen's songs, which are fan's
 favorite things, appears.

@ 소원성취=소취=fulfilling a wish : 소취곡 is a song that fan want
to hear.

Comment: is 퀸 the name of song or singer?

Comment: 퀸 is a famous rock group (as you know). In the sentence, by 소취곡, 퀸의 노래를 세상에 나오게 ... So it may be a typo. However,  in real situation, we can say 소취곡 퀸을 세상에 나오게 ...